# CSS second-line indent not working

Tags: css

Page in question: http://www.rjlacount.com/public/lander/

I'm probably just doing something stupid, but I'm trying to indent the second line of wrapping text inside the form (with "Your account: test@test.com" at the top) and I can't seem to get anything to work.

I would think the solution is:

```
form span {padding-left:1.5em;text-indent:-1.5em;}
```

but this only seems to indent the first line of each section.

Another look at this would be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: This will not work. You have to either position radio box and the text or put each into a floating container.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If the element is inline it will indent the first line, otherwise if it's a block element it will indent the rest of the lines, which is just like Briguy37 said, since that's the difference between DIV and SPAN. 
I just wanted to clear out that it's not a "problem with span".

Answer (score 3):

For some reason, this works with a DIV, but not with a SPAN.  Not really sure why, but [here](http://jsfiddle.net/briguy37/sTJ7X/)'s a fiddle with the same CSS for both.

Comment: Weird. Thanks for the response. Wrapping each input in a <p> tag works too. Seems kinda weird, but it'll work.

Comment: `<span>` is inline by default, while `<div>` and `<p>` are block by default. I haven't tried it, but I bet if you set `display:block` on the span and `display:inline` on the div, you'll reverse the indentation behavior. ;)

Answer (score 2):

spans are handled as inline elements.

Considering them as actual characters helps to conceptualize the changes.  A space after a span is retained because it's like a space between characters.  You adjust height by line-height rather than simply height.  etc etc

Usually if this is causing a problem you can just use a div and set display:inline-block;  if you need horizontal alignment.